# How to get metadata of an existing document in a sharepoint library (in vba or vbs)

Tags: sharepoint, vba, vbscript, metadata

I have a document in a sharepoint library, say http://myserver/mysite/mylib/mydoc1.pdf, how can I access metadata properties of the document mydoc1.pdf?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use your `term data store`, have the information entered at the site collection level and grab it from all your libraries.